# Jquery animating position moving when click on it

Tags: jquery, animation

I have some `a` tag with `position:absolute`, and when I click on it, I want to move this tag 100px left (animated).

How to do this?

Comment: Am I missing something? Did [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate) not work?

Comment: @Atic give me few mitues i will provide u a example

Comment: @Atic , i did a jsfiddle try this example http://jsfiddle.net/EtfCV/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will move your element (having an ID of `#my_link`) 100 pixels to the left when clicked.

```
$('#my_link').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '-=100'
    });
});
```

- [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate)
- [jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? You can animate CSS properties such as `left`.

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'left' : '-=100'});
});
```

Comment: One less `)` would be perfect :).

Answer (score 2):

this should do it

jsfiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/EtfCV/

```
$('#yourdiv').click(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: '-=100'
      }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
```

Comment: +1 basically same as mine. I would remove the comma after `'-=100'`, some browsers won't like it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CWcPM/), and the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate) method at the jQuery site. It's really basic stuff.

```
$('#tralala').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate({
        left : '-=100'
    });
});
```